# How to set up a correct cascade with label statement

Tags: html, css

I am styling a checkbox.  The HTML in the file fin1.cfm is:

```
 <td>Master Event:</td>
 <td>
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "cb_e" name = "datesumm" value = "" >
    <label for = "cb_e">&nbsp; </label>
 </td>
```

The CSS in the file betty.css is:

```
 label {  
    display: inline-block;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    position: relative;  
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 15px;  
    margin-right: 0px;  
    font-size: 13px;  
} 

input[type=checkbox] {  
    display: none;  
}

label:before {  
content: "";  
display: inline-block;  
width: 30px;  
height: 20px;  
margin-right: 0px;  
position: absolute; 
left: 10;  
bottom: 1px;  
background-color: #E6F2F0;     
box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8); 
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 }  

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {  
   content: "D"; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);  
    font-size: 15px;  input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before
    color: red;
    text-align: center;  
    line-height: 15px;
    padding-top: 7px;         
}
```

My problem is with the **content** in the `input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before` statement.

In one place I do need the content to be "D" as indicated.  However, I have another place where I want the content to be something else, such as a check mark.

I can't seem to find a way to structure this to get that result.  I've tried putting the statement in a different CSS file, but the betty.css file is invoked in the calling program, and apparently it rules.  I've also tried setting up a class for that statement, and referencing that in the HTML label tag, but I haven't been able make it work.

Can someone show me how to get different content in different places?

Comment: how many of these checkboxes do you have? can you use `id`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but you can have a generic rule for all checkboxes followed by a more specific rule for a specific checkbox (which overrides one property from the generic rule).

Something along the lines of:

**UPDATED (based on comments)**

```
/* this is the default setting for all checkboxes */
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
      content: "D";
    }

    /* you could list ids here or simply add another class (like .customCheck below) */
    input#cb_f:checked + label:before,
    input.customCheck:checked + label:before,
    input#cb_f3:checked + label:before {
      content: "\2713";
    }
```

It is easier to use the custom class (`.customCheck` - you can call it anything) than to list all possible `id`s.

If using custom class, simply add it to your HTML, like I did at the end here:

`<input type="checkbox" id="cb_f2" name="datesumm" value="" class="customCheck">`

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
  bottom: 1px;
  background-color: #E6F2F0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

/* this is the default setting for all checkboxes */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: "D";
}

/* you could list ids here or simply add another class (like .customCheck below) */
input#cb_f:checked + label:before,
input.customCheck:checked + label:before,
input#cb_f3:checked + label:before {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Master Event:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e" name="datesumm" value="">
      <label for="cb_e">&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Master Event2:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e2" name="datesumm" value="">
      <label for="cb_e2">&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Master Event3:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb_e3" name="datesumm" value="">
      <label for="cb_e3">&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Secondary Event:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb_f" name="datesumm" value="">
      <label for="cb_f">&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Secondary Event2:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb_f2" name="datesumm" value="" class="customCheck">
      <label for="cb_f2">&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Secondary Even3:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb_f3" name="datesumm" value="" class="customCheck">
      <label for="cb_f3">&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The snippet looks promising -- I'll check it out within my code shortly.

Comment: Hi Ochi,  got it basically working, but wonder if you can answer another question.  For the D I have an unknown number of boxes, so that has to be the default.  For the check mark I have 3 boxes, each with a different id.  Can I stack all 3 id's in one statement; and if so what would be the syntax?

Comment: Yes, very helpful.  I did try it with classes, but couldn't get all the various pieces into the right places.

Comment: @BettyMock care to elaborate? from the original requirements, this answers the question but perhaps I missed something else?

Comment: You missed nothing.  Your code samples are exactly what I needed.  I think before I put the class in the wrong place in the CSS as in input:checked + label:before.class1 {  ... The checkboxes are now operating properly using class "class1".  The only remaining puzzle is that the form does not send the checked values through; could that be because of the formatting?  I'm doing it manually with Javascript, setting a hidden input when the box is checked (or unchecked).

Comment: I am glad I could help.  As for the remaining puzzle, ask a new question for the new issue and let's see if we can find out why.  Make sure to include a basic example of the form and how you are submitting it.

Comment: okay, I set it up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180339/not-picking-up-form-values-from-checkbox -- cannot find any documentation on the right way to pick up checked values, so any help is appreciated.